# Input value doesn't change right away with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, placeholder

I'm creating a jQuery placeholder that acts like chrome/firefox default placeholders for browsers that don't support but I can't get the placholder div's html to change as fast as how the default placeholder for chrome/firefox changes. It only changes when I let go of the key or if you leave a key pressed it only changes when there's at least 2 characters in the input. How can I fix this?

http://jsfiddle.net/HW7tK/2/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Place Holder</title>
        <style media="screen" type="text/css">
        input{
            position:absolute;
            top:4px;
            left:4px;
            background:transparent;
        }
        #default{
            top:30px;
        }
        #ph{
            color:LightGray;
        }
        </style>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            $("#txt")
                .keypress(function(){
                    if($('#txt').val().length > 0){
                        $('#ph').html('');
                    } else {
                        $('#ph').html('Custom Place Holder');
                    }
                })
                .keyup(function() {
                    if($('#txt').val().length > 0){
                        $('#ph').html('');
                    } else {
                        $('#ph').html('Custom Place Holder');
                    }
                });
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="ph">Custom Place Holder</div>
        <input id="txt" type="text"  />
        <input id="default" type="text" placeholder="Default Placeholder"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I fixed the issue using timers(setTimeout) but I don't know if it's good practice to use timers in this kind of situation. http://jsfiddle.net/HW7tK/10/

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if it makes *that* much difference, but I made the small change to using `keydown` in place of `keypress` and visually looks pretty indistinguishable from the default behaviour:

http://jsfiddle.net/HW7tK/4/

Comment: I just did the same , I didnt see a difference though

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Instead of append html, try to hide the div. It may fulfill your satisfaction

```
 if($('#txt').val().length > 0){
                    $('#ph').hide();
                } else {
                    $('#ph').show();
                }
```

Comment: It still has the same problem. It's not that big of a problem but it's been bugging me and I haven't been able to fix it myself.